# Is self injection a good practice? Same class injection programming pattern in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, anti-patterns

Is injection of the same class a good practice?

I am using self-injection for years **to isolate methods during PHPunit testing**:

```
class Meter extends Model
{
    use SomeTrait;

    protected self $self;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->self = $this;
    }

    public function setSelfDI(self $self): self
    {
        $this->self = $self;
        return $this;
    }

    public function calculate(): int
    {
        return $this->self->getDiametr() * 3.1415926;
    }
    
    public function getDiametr(): int
    {
        return parent::getRadius() * 2;
    }
    
}
```

to test calculate() method I can't just call it since it calls method getDiametr() which depends on other trait or class.
And I believe it is bad practice to test mocked class.

So I inject mocked class in my class and so isolate method during testing:

```
public function testCalculate(): void
{
    /** @var Meter|MockObject $mock */
    $mock = $this->createMock(Meter::class);
    $mock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getDiametr')
        ->willReturn(100);
        
    $meter = new Meter();
    $meter->setSelfDI($mock);
    static::assertEquals(314.15926, $meter->calculate());
}
```

It works perfectly for me.

But recently I got a code review that it is not a valid pattern to introduce synthetic functionality setSelfDI() on top of functional code just to be able to test it.

Now I have a normal DI pattern that I love to use vs setSelfDI() setter that is never used but for tests.

How to decide it is good or bad practice?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31456610/157957) showed up in the "Related Questions" sidebar and has two answers with similar conclusions to my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe it is bad practice to test mocked class.

If you really believe that, you have answered your own question, because that's exactly what you're doing - you're mocking some methods of the class and testing others.

It's important not to just read a bulleted list of "best practices" but to understand *why* each of those rules is proposed. In this case, the idea is that you should have a particular "unit" of code that you are testing; functionality that is the responsibility of that "unit" should be tested, and functionality that it *relies on* should be decoupled and tested separately.

That's not just a recommendation about testing, it's a recommendation about architecting your code - the Single Responsibility Principle.

In your example, the better design might be one of several things:

- If the radius is just data, you don't need to mock it, create a real instance with a known radius
- If calculating the radius is the responsibility of some other component with its own tests, pass in that object as a dependency rather than inheriting from it (commonly summarised, "prefer composition over inheritance")
- If calculating the data is not an input or independent calculation in the real code, don't treat it as one in the test: you should be testing the *contract* of the class - its inputs, outputs, and side effects - not *how* it is implemented

If radius is an input to the class being tested, the test would be simple:

```php
public function testCalculate(): void
{
    $meter = new Meter(['radius' => 50);
    static::assertEquals(314.15926, $meter->calculate());
}
```

Using composition rather than inheritance, you might have a test like this:

```php
public function testCalculate(): void
{
    // Mock the collaborating class, not the one being tested
    $mock = $this->createMock(Model::class);

    // Note that we're mocking getRadius, not getDiametr
    // getDiametr is part of the implementation we're testing
    $mock->method('getRadius')
        ->willReturn(50);
        
    // Meter doesn't inherit from Model
    // Instead, it requires an instance to be injected
    $meter = new Meter($mock);
    static::assertEquals(314.15926, $meter->calculate());
}
```

Note that in both cases the parts that we're hard-coding in the test are the radius of 50 and the result of 314.15926, not the diameter of 100 - the *contract* that we're testing is "given a radius of 50, the result should be 314.15926". The fact that calculate() shares code with getDiametr() is the *implementation* by which you've fulfilled that contract.

The following implementations should all pass **the same tests**. The point of the tests is to guarantee that after you've changed the implementation, the contract hasn't been violated - in other words, the code will still do what the rest of your application expects it to do.

```php
// Fully shared
class Meter {
    // ...

    public function calculate(): int
    {
        return $this->getDiameter() * 3.1415926;
    }
    
    public function getDiameter(): int
    {
        return $this->getRadius() * 2;
    }
}
```

```php
// Fully copy-and-pasted
class Meter {
    // ...

    public function calculate(): int
    {
        return $this->getRadius() * 2 * 3.1415926;
    }
    
    public function getDiameter(): int
    {
        return $this->getRadius() * 2;
    }
}
```

```php
// Partially shared
class Meter {
    // ...

    private function getDiameterInternal(): int
    {
        return $this->getRadius() * 2;
    }

    public function calculate(): int
    {
        return $this->getDiameterInternal() * 3.1415926;
    }
    
    public function getDiameter(): int
    {
        return $this->getDiameterInternal();
    }
}
```

```php
// Delegated to a dependency, but still meeting the original contract
class Meter {
    // ...

    private $someOtherObject;

    public function calculate(): int
    {
        return $this->someOtherObject->getDiameter() * 3.1415926;
    }
    
    public function getDiameter(): int
    {
        return $this->someOtherObject->getDiameter();
    }
}
```

Any of the above methods could also be in a Trait, which represents neither inheritance nor composition, but "horizontal code reuse", or more plainly "compiler-assisted copy-and-paste".

Comment: methods like getRadius() are developed in Laravel framework, 3rd party code. Can you please give a link to proper test sample doing those 'testing the contract of the class - its inputs, outputs, and side effects - not how it is implemented'?

Comment: @EugeneKaurov I've added some examples and some more explanation of what I mean by the "contract".

Comment: @MSoP Thanks a lot for the samples. Still, our discussion was started about traits. Laravel has lots of them. As far I know trait can't be injected into the variable, only used. This automatically means inheritance. Also, what about test isolation?  static::assertEquals(314.15926, $meter->calculate()); will test not only calculate() but also used public function getDiametr() which has separate test.

Comment: You say "our discussion was started about traits", but I hadn't particularly noticed that traits were involved. Note that traits are *not* inheritance, they are "compiler assisted copy and paste"; you can just as easily "paste" them into a parent class, or into a separate dependency. Either way, my advice remains to think about **responsibilities** and **contracts**. "getDiametr" _shouldn't_ need any tests of its own, because it has no contract that code outside the class is relying on; it exists only as part of the implementation of `calculate()`, which has a public contract.

Comment: getDiametr() is public and useful method that is used from outside and needs test

Comment: @EugeneKaurov The real code making use of this class can't tell, and doesn't care, if calculate() and getDiametr() call each other, share some implementation by calling a private method, or just have copied and pasted code. It's therefore _entirely counter-productive_ to write a test that locks in the current design. The tests for calculate() are about making sure that code _outside_ the class can rely on the result of calculate(). That's what I mean by "contract": what does _the rest of your application expect_ when it calls calculate().